# Performing subqueries in Django ORM from two different databases

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models Model1 and Model2 where table for Model1 is defined in db1 and for Model2 it is defined in db2. I have router set up for read operations from both the databases which is working fine for simple read operations, but for complex annotations and Subqueries I am unable to figure out how to make the ORM understand which DB to search the tables in.

This is what I am trying to do right now:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
from app1.models import Model1
from app2.models import Model2

model1_qs = Model1.objects.using('db1').filter(id=OuterRef('context_id'))
model2_qs = Model2.objects.using('db2').all()

res = model2_qs.objects.using('db1').annotate(
    model1_value=Subquery(model1_qs.values('value')[:1])
)
```

I am expecting `res` to be an annotated queryset with `model1_value` fetched from `db1`. But instead getting a table not found error. Django is trying to look for Model1 in db2...

P.S. I need to perform such queries in existing views of a large project, so using raw SQL queries is not really a feasible option for me.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, a single query in Django can't span databases.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/multi-db/ checkout djangoproject with multi database docs

Comment: @TanveerAhmad I have already set up router for multiple databases, the problem is in queries including subqueries...

Comment: nope go down more you will see how to queries from different db.

Comment: @abhigyashridhar: well this can not work, since the first database does not know about the second, hence it does not have an object named `model1`. Even raw queries do not work for this.